# Linear or Switching DC/DC Regulator ? Single or Multiple outputs?

Tags: switching-regulator

I have a doubt in wich approach to use. I will explain my doubt, and probably it is a doubt of others too.

I'm redesigning my Embedded hardware and I'm needing an multi output power supply with at least 3 outputs. I need a 3.3V, 5V and 12V( so, if I choose a switching regulator, it could be a buck converter ).  So I have some general questions:

*1) Wich approach to use, a linear regulator or a switch regulator ?*

*2) To use a regulator with multiple outputs, or use 3 regulators, one to each output voltage ?*

**1) Wich approach to use, a linear regulator or a switch regulator ?**

To try to answer this question, I made a search on web and found some interesting tips. In the Maxin's site:

https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/2031

There is a topic, "Why Use a Switching Regulator?" in which it try to explain the benefits  and some drawbacks using a switching regulator. Three points catched my attention, one is the fact that using a switching regulator enable us to use smaller components, the second is the fact that less thermal management is required, and the third that it can be noisy and energy management could be required.

The following site:

http://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2012/may/understanding-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-linear-regulators

makes a comparison to help to choose between a switching and a linear regulator. Among others explanations, many times is used the argument of the boost capability to justify how a switching regulator  can be good for solutions using battery.  And, similar to the previous link of Maxin's explanation, it says that less thermal management is required with a switching regulator, and that linear regulator has a more "clean" output .

My aplication does not need a battery and needs only buck converters, so, for me, the boost capability's argument is irrelevant. The less thermal management is very important because I don't want to use big heatsinks. About the  "clean" output, it is a very interesting issue because my aplication has some features, like bluetooth and LF RFID(Low Frequency  Radio Frequency Identification), and I don't know if the noise added by a switch regulator can interfere.

So, first, I will divide in two issues to choose between linear and switching regulator.

- *1.1) Power dissipation*
- *1.2) Noise*

  **1.1) Power dissipation**

I did not find a formal definition about whether or not to use a switched regulator, however, on the following link:

https://www.dimensionengineering.com/info/switching-regulators

is used, as a rule of thumb, verify if the solution with the linear voltage regulator is wasting more than 0.5 watts. More dissipation implies larger heatsinks, which could lead to greater space occupation besides besides to have to calculate the heatsink. So, considering this 0.5W's rule and, as an illustration, I took a quick look at the microcontroller  that I plan to use ,MC9S12XEP100, and found that it can drain about 100mA into its analog power source pin and under a voltage of 5V. So, considering a 13.8V input source (which is the one we currently have in the lab), we could have:

Power wasted = (input voltage – output voltage) * load current
             = ( 13.8 - 5 ) * 0,1
             = 0,88 W

The input source voltage can have from 12V up to 24 V. Considering the case of using as input a 24V source, this value rises to 1.9W, and, if we consider a 24V source, for an output voltage of 3.3V (because the microcontroller can also be operated with this voltage , and we will need this voltage to other elements on the hardware) this value could rise to about  2.07 W, remembering that this was obtained taking into consideration only the microcontroller!

So based on this explanation, I would to decide to use a switching regulator, am I right ?

**1.2) Noise**

A switching regulator can add noise like was warned everywhere. So, I will make the following question:

Could this noise be critical to my application ?

I didn't find explicitly explanations about this, so, I will put here my concerns about it.

- Bluetooth module (2.4 GHz)
- LF RFID (Low Frequency Radio Frequency Identification)  module (125 kHz)

The following illustration try to show how it could be mounted.

[image]

Can the bluetooth module and the LF RFID transponder's reader/writer be affected by a switching regulator ? The LF FRID module can be directly connected to the main board by a five wire connector and it is powered by the main board using 5V or 3.3V. And about bluetooth ? I'm thinking to use the CC2650MODA from Texas Instruments.

**2) Use a regulator with multiple outputs, or use 3 regulators, one to each output voltage ?**

I thought that using a single chip could lead to less components, decreasing the price and using less space. I really don't have many others explanations to justify this and I don't know about drawbacks in use multiple outputs.

Comment: Is you bluetooth and RFID running from the 3.3V Rail???

Comment: I would be happy to answer any question, but reading all that?.. Rephrase, divide to several questions

Comment: Yes, my bluetooth will be running from 3.3V,  but the RFID, initially running from 5V,  will be running from 3.3V in the future.

Comment: I'm sorry Gregory Kornblum for the text so big,  my intention was to transfer information along with the question, so as to try to form a case of study that could service as reference for others.